# Why are my flow tests failing to check the transaction in certain nodes even if they are present on their storages?

Tags: java, corda

> ERROR: java.lang.AssertionError: expected: net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction but was: net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction
>       Expected :net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction 
>       Actual   :net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction

As far I see, the both expected and actual transactions are same, but it is still throwing the error. It was passing in other tests but failed suddenly without any satisfactory info to debug.
below is the code from my tests:

```
@Test
    public void flowRecordsATransactionInBothPartiesTransactionStorages() throws Exception {
        SignedTransaction signedTx = createPlacementCompleteTxn();

        // We check the recorded transaction in both vaults.
        for (StartedMockNode node : ImmutableList.of(participantsNodes.get(0), participantsNodes.get(1), participantsNodes.get(3))) {
            assertEquals(signedTx, node.getServices().getValidatedTransactions().getTransaction(signedTx.getId()));
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked `equals()` method for `net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction` class?
You can also use debug to manually explore properties of those objects.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me on Corda 4. For example, the following test passes:

```
@Test
public void recordedTransactionIsCorrect() throws Exception {
    ExampleFlow.Initiator flow = new ExampleFlow.Initiator(1, b.getInfo().getLegalIdentities().get(0));
    CordaFuture<SignedTransaction> future = a.startFlow(flow);
    network.runNetwork();
    SignedTransaction signedTx = future.get();

    // We check the recorded transaction in both vaults.
    for (StartedMockNode node : ImmutableList.of(a, b)) {
        SignedTransaction recordedTx = node.getServices().getValidatedTransactions().getTransaction(signedTx.getId());
        assertEquals(recordedTx, signedTx);
    }
}
```